# Incorrect reels colors on mobile instagram

Tags: color-correction, color

After uploading the reels to the profile after what time (about 1 hour) the colours on the video become not very saturated. For example, the orange colour becomes almost yellow - it looks terrible. Only the first frame of the reel is in good colours.

I uploaded the same reel via an android phone and after a couple of hours the reel still looks ok - no such problem.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause something like this? Maybe some specific iOS settings?

https://instagram.com/klev.lb here's a profile with this same issue on 3 last reels and illustrates exactly the problem that I have.